# WebView.Navigate results in unhandled exception

Tags: windows-8, webview, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

Using the WebView control in the [Windows 8 SDK Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-WebView-control-sample-58ad63f7) results in an unhandled 'Unspecified error'. 
In my own project it gives me an unhandled exception of 'Unable to get property '1' of undefined or null reference'.

I can't catch it.

It doesn't happen if I deploy it to a Surface or on another machine so I think it's probably my machine.

I need to know what I can do to fix this issue on my machine.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you are catching javascript exception. You can see it on your computer since you run the app under the debugger. Once you deploy the app to another computer javascript exception still happens, but it gets silently ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you debug a XAML app with a WebView whose content has a JavaScript exception, that exception is elevated up through the WebView to Visual Studio where you (presumably) can debug it. When you run this (CTRL+F5) without debugging, these types of errors are swallowed. So your experience is not your machine, but the fact that the debugger is attached.

You can find a similar question and its answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12249831/265706 But beware that the answer to that question suggests disabling the debugging mechanism. Make sure that is what you really want to do.

Comment: Thanks Jerry, I couldn't replicate the javascript exception outside of  debugging. Desktop IE10 doesn't throw any exceptions although it does warn about blocking scripts.

Comment: I think that sometimes the reason is because the webview implements less than the browser. JavaScript is expecting something that is not there. I have not found the pattern for it. My experience is the same as yours.